# Qualititative inorganic analysis

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry

Why is it that a specific order is followed while performing qualitative inorganic analysis? I mean, why are we told to first test for the anion in the given salt (and there is an order to be followed for which anion to test for first, which second and so on) and then for the cation?

Does it really matter which way we do it?
How does it affect the analysis if we don't follow the order of cations/anions?

Comment: It is just a matter of preference. If you wish to test for the cation first, you can do that and nothing is going to change. Generally the order is given to make the job easy for students, so they can remeber the tests (and also because the profs. know which salt is generally given and the given order is the order of probability. Like if there are 4 salts with sulfate ions, it is better to do the test for sulfates first).